# Python unable to parse Json file with error "raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to download a Json file from an API and convert it into a csv file, but the script throws the below error while parsing the json file.

For every 100 records json file closes the "]" and starts  another "[". This format is not being accepted as json format. could you please suggest me how i can parse the "]" and "[" which appears every 100 records in an efficient way.The code works fine for less than 100 records without the [] brackets.

```
Error message:

raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

Json file format:

```
**[**
    {
        "A": "5",
        "B": "811",
        "C": [
            {   "C1": 1,
                "C2": "sa",
                "C3": 3
                
            }
        ],
        "D": "HH",
        "E": 0,
        "F": 6
    },
    {
        "A": "5",
        "B": "811",
        "C": [
            {   "C1": 1,
                "C2": "fa",
                "C3": 3
                
            }
        ],
        "D": "HH",
        "E": 0,
        "F": 6
    }
    **]**
    **[**
    {
        "A": "5",
        "B": "811",
        "C": [
            {   "C1": 1,
                "C2": "da",
                "C3": 3
                
            }
        ],
        "D": "HH",
        "E": 0,
        "F": 6
    }
    **]**
```

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten

def json2excel():
    file_path = r"<local file path>"
    json_list = json.load(open(file_path + '.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
    key_list = ['A', 'B']
    json_list = [{k: d[k] for k in key_list} for d in json_list]
    # Flatten and convert to a data frame
    json_list_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in json_list)
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_list_flattened)
    # Export to CSV in the same directory with the original file name
    export_csv = df.to_csv(file_path + r'.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=None, header=True)

def main():
    json2excel()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend parsing your data that you receive from your API first. This pre-processed data can be fed to a JSON parser later.

I came up with a simple python code that's just a small tweak to the solution of parenthesis matching problem. Here's my working code that you might use for pre-processing your data.

```
def build_json_items(custom_json): 
    open_tup = tuple('({[') 
    close_tup = tuple(')}]') 
    map = dict(zip(open_tup, close_tup)) 
    queue = [] 
    
    json_items = []
    temp = ""
    for i in custom_json:
        if i in open_tup: 
            queue.append(map[i]) 
        elif i in close_tup: 
            if not queue or i != queue.pop(): 
                return "Unbalanced"
        
        if len(queue) == 0: 
            # We have reached to a point where everything so far is balanced. 
            # This is the point where we can separate out the expression
            temp = temp + str(i)
            json_items.append(temp)
            temp = "" # Re-initialize
        else:
            temp = temp + str(i)

    if not queue:
        # Provided string is balanced
        return True, json_items
    else: 
        return False, json_items
```

This `build_json_items` function will take your custom JSON payload and will parse individual valid JSON items based on the information that you provided in your question. Here's an example of how you can trigger this function. You can use the following.

```
input_data = "[{\"A\":\"5\",\"B\":\"811\",\"C\":[{\"C1\":1,\"C2\":\"sa\",\"C3\":3}],\"D\":\"HH\",\"E\":0,\"F\":6},{\"A\":\"5\",\"B\":\"811\",\"C\":[{\"C1\":1,\"C2\":\"fa\",\"C3\":3}],\"D\":\"HH\",\"E\":0,\"F\":6}][{\"A\":\"5\",\"B\":\"811\",\"C\":[{\"C1\":1,\"C2\":\"da\",\"C3\":3}],\"D\":\"HH\",\"E\":0,\"F\":6}]"

is_balanced, json_items = build_json_items(input_data)
print(f"Available JSON items: {len(json_items)}")
print("JSON items are the following")
for i in json_items: 
    print(i)
```

Here's the output of the print statements.

```
Available JSON items: 2
JSON items are the following
[{"A":"5","B":"811","C":[{"C1":1,"C2":"sa","C3":3}],"D":"HH","E":0,"F":6},{"A":"5","B":"811","C":[{"C1":1,"C2":"fa","C3":3}],"D":"HH","E":0,"F":6}]
[{"A":"5","B":"811","C":[{"C1":1,"C2":"da","C3":3}],"D":"HH","E":0,"F":6}]
```

You can [directly run and see the output here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wp3dxcbu).

Once you have those payloads separated in valid JSON structure, you can feed these to you JSON parser.